# Array sorting is showing different results everytime

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I might have close to 40 elements in the array. Ocasionally the array is sorted as I want it to be sorted but after I refresh the webpage, the order of sorting completely changes even if the information itself remains the same and the process of sorting is the same.

I notice that I get "2000 messages have not been logged" in the console, so I assume the logger gets overloaded.

Therefore, my first question is: **do javascript executions have any 'timeout' as in a php script, for example?**

And if not, what could be wrong with my code?

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {

      var a_freq = a["first"],
            b_freq = b["first"],
            a_imp = a["second"],
            b_imp = b["second"],
            a_ldone = a["third"],
            b_ldone = b["third"];

      var imp_diff = (a_imp - b_imp) / 10;

      var relation;

          if (imp_diff == 0){

              if(b_ldone > a_ldone){
                  return 1;
              }else if(b_ldone == a_ldone){
                  if(a_freq >= b_freq){
                      return 1;
                  }else{ 
                      return -1;
                  }
              }else{
                  return -1;
              }

          }else if(imp_diff > 0){

              if(b_ldone > imp_diff && a_ldone - b_ldone > imp_diff){
                  return 1;
              }

              return -1;

          }else{

              imp_diff = imp_diff * (-1);

              if(a_ldone > imp_diff && b_ldone - a_ldone > imp_diff){

                  return -1;

              }

              return 1;

          }

      }

    });
```

When I **return 1**, am I advancing element 'a' or 'b'?

As I said, **the values stay the same with every refresh of the webpage** but for some reason the order changes... Within every refresh, though, **the value of the final array is saved in the cache**, so the new array that is being sorted in a refresh is an array that has been sorted previously, but the values of each objet in the array stay the same... Any reason for it to change, sometimes so abruptly? Does the javascript process simply halt without completely finishing sorting the whole array? What would be the reason for this? As I wrote, I must have around 40/50 elements in the array... Is this too much to handle? Is there any other possible motif?

Comment: Well for one thing a `.sort()` callback is supposed to return -1, 0, or 1, but yours only ever returns -1 or 1.

Comment: actually it can return any number - sorting numbers I always return a-b for instance, and having no 0 will probably just mean a slightly longer time to sort

Comment: The only timeout in Javascript is when the script takes so long that the browser pops up a dialogue asking if you want to kill the script.

Comment: @JaromandaX - If you don't ever return 0 then it won't know which items are supposed to be equal. (But yes, you can return any positive or negative number rather than just 1 or -1 for non-equal items.)

Comment: You say that the order completely changes. Do you mean that it's not following the ordering rules in the comparison function?

Comment: I've seen sorts that return only -1 and 1 that have equal items, but sort works fine

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the different orderings that result?

Comment: 40-50 elements is an incredibly tiny array. `sort()` should handle arrays with millions of items with no problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Oh. I'm sure I've seen a previous question where that didn't work, but...wait, maybe I'm thinking of a case where somebody was returning a boolean, which obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: Really boils down to you need to provide a [mcve] that displays this behavior if you want help. We have no idea what you are inputting. From MDN Docs `compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.`

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why would we expect anything in the browser to be retained after a page refresh?  JS memory is flushed...

Comment: I see a few possible inconsistencies.

Comment: @AmelieTurgeon Care to elaborate please?

Comment: @anied I'm using html5 storage

Comment: @nnnnnn in this context what does returning -1,0 or 1 do? If I return 1 does "a" get close do index zero? Or is it returning -1? And zero?

Comment: Return a negative number if item `a` should come before item `b`,  return 0 if they're equal, and return a positive number if `a` should come after `b`.

Comment: @nnnnnn and who was close to index zero at the start? a or b? And by before do you mean subtracting its index position or incrementing it?

Comment: I mean "before" in the sense that D comes before R in alphabetic order, and 6 comes before 11 in numeric order.

Comment: You're examining multiple keys in the comparison function, but it's being done in a way that does not make sense in any clear way. Generally, a multi-key sort only proceeds to secondary and tertiary (etc) keys when the primary keys compare as equal. Comparing secondary keys when the primary keys are *unequal* does not really make sense, at least without knowing more about what the meanings are of the values you're comparing.

Comment: @Fane I'm sure I edited my comment, but I may have forgotten to. Are there any chances that a and b may be equals wrt their subvalues without being equals? Then all those values may swich places from one load to the other. It's the normal way of a sort function. And without knowing more about your problem area, I can't really get my head around what goes on if imp_diff != 0.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Returning `(a-b)` can cause problems with integer overflow in some languages. For example if `a` is a very large positive number (like `int.MaxValue` in C#), and `b` is negative (for example, `-2200`), then `(a-b)` will return a positive value, falsely indicating that `a < b`.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Some sorting implementations can go into an infinite loop if the comparison function doesn't return 0 for equal items. If `compare(a,b)` returns 1, then the expectation is that `compare(b,a)` will return -1. If you don't return 0 for equal items, then that expectation cannot be met, and the algorithm can do very strange things. That it works for some implementations just means that you've been lucky. I've seen implementations in which it doesn't work.